# How to setup plugins for ollydbg 2.x.x?

Tags: plugins, assembly, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I downloaded the latest ollydbg 2.x version from its official site and some plugins from tuts4you. But how to enable/install the plugins?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- either you put the plugin dll inside a dedicated directory (e.g. `Plugins`) or in the same directory than ollydbg.exe
- in the `Options / Options... / Directories` panel, configure the `Plugin directory` setting accordingly to the place where you put the dll. If you put the dll in ollydbg.exe directory, you can set `.`
- restart OllyDbg
- you should have a `plugins` menu where the plugins add their menus entry points

This is a general procedure, you might need to adapt for specific plugins : e.g. some may need additional .txt or .ini files. This should be described inside the plugin package.

Also, if you have done this settings and still cannot see your plugin, beware that the plugin API had a recent major upgrade for version 2.01h. Some existing plugins may not be supported anymore.

If you don't have you plugin source code or cannot rebuild it yourself it is possible to try to patch the plugin dll to let it load in Olly. This is tricky because you need to patch the version number, and probably the callbacks in the dll concerned by the plugin api. The procedure is described [in a screencast](http://sluganalysislab.blogspot.com/2012/10/ollydbg-2xx-plugin-compatibility.html).