# OllyDbg - Plugins menu is grayed out (OllyDbg 2.0.1)

Tags: plugins, ollydbg

I've tried every version of OllyDbg 2.0.1 (including Alpha and Beta versions) and no matter what, the 'Plugins' menu on the top bar is grayed out. Is there a fix for this without going back to version 1.10? Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried to use some Olly v1 plugins with Olly v2? The plugin API has changed and there might have incompatibilities. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14580133/317266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just not supported yet and probably will get a long time to start supporting plugins, the developer its focusing on 64bit version of olly right now (if he still developing), but if you want to go to other olly like debugger you can try ImmunityDbg, it's basically olly but from other developer.